# Display data in two different TableView in the same View in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, swift2

I'm creating an app for iPad, and because of their size decided to do something a little different. I'm creating something like this:

[image]

I am using two UITableView in a UIView. I need to display data 'product categories' in the first TableView and 'products' in the second TableView.

The problem is display data in two tables with direferentes contents.
Another detail: When a category is selected, the table 'product' is recharged with other data of other products.

My question is: **How can I display data in two different TableView in the same View**?

Comment: You can take two container views and embed a table view controller in each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add two Containers to your View Controller and drag from the container view to your desired Table View Controller and click embed. Then you'll need to make two separate UITableViewController Cocoa files and assign them to the table view in your Identity Inspector.

In this picture I've already attached the container on the left to my Table View Controller on the left.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! And to make the communication between them, use segues?

Comment: You might be able to pull it off in a number of ways but I'd personally use NSNotificationCenter. Here's a tutorial: https://www.codebeaulieu.com/41/introduction-to-NSNotificationCenter-tutorial

Comment: @James you could also try using a Protocol / Delegate pattern: https://www.codebeaulieu.com/36/Passing-data-with-the-protocol-delegate-pattern

Comment: What is the advantage in using a container? Why not just adding multiple tableviews to one ViewController?

Comment: This is just the way I do it, there may be alternatives but I believe they all require you to embed your separate table view controllers in some sort of individual view that will render them.

Comment: @Darko I was looking for a way to re-use a small table view (that segues to another views) in 3 different screens. So I couldn't use a XIB. Embedding my re-usable table view in a container view, that's the way!