# Pass data by protocol while using Container to view another ViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, swift-protocols

I started working on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213813/display-data-in-two-different-tableview-in-the-same-view-in-swift/) app. 
I began by tableView of the categories:

[image]

For data exchange, I decided to use a protocol:

```
protocol Category {
    func data(object:AnyObject)
}
```

In the first ViewController has the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var items:[String] = ["Desktop","Tablet","Phone"]

    let CategoriesData:Category? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CategoriesData?.data(items)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

In the second ViewController (tableView in Container) have the following code:

```
class CategoriesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, Category  {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    var items:[String] = []

    func data(object: AnyObject) {
        self.items = (object as? [String])!
        print(object)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:TableViewCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SegueStage") as! TableViewCell

        cell.nameLabel.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

For me, apparently it's all right. But nothing appeared on the simulator.

[image]

My question is: **If the Container use to present another viewController as passing data by protocols should be done**?

Comment: You start out with `CategoriesData` as nil.  How does that ever change?  (Using a protocol is fine but you still need a reference to the object that implements the protocol.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED

I answered why the TO:s solution didn't work as intended, but I just realised that I haven't given a viable answer to how to use protocols as delegates for the `ViewController` -> `ViewController` communication. I'll leave the half-answer below until someone can possibly answer the full question better.

---

In the way `protocol` is used in your code, you define your protocol `Category` to be a delegate for *instances* of the type `ViewController`. When an instance of type `ViewController` is initialised in---and hence owned locally in the scope of---some other class, the instance can delegate callbacks to the owning class.

The problem is that your `CategoriesViewController` does not contain any instances of type `ViewController`. We note that both these classes are, in themselves, subclasses of `UIViewController`, but none of them contain instances of one another. Hence, your `CategoriesViewController` does indeed conform to protocol `Category`, by implemented the protocol method `data(...)`, but there's no `ViewController` instance in `CategoriesViewController` that can do callbacks to this function. Hence, your code compile file, but as it is, method `data(...)` in `CategoriesViewController` will never be called.

I might be mistaken, but as far as I know, protocol delegates are used to do callbacks between models (for model in MVC design) and controllers (see example below), whereas in your case, you want a delegate directly between two controllers.

---

As an example of model-delegate-controller design, consider some custom user control, with some key property `value` (e.g. position in rating control), implemented as a subclass of `UIView`:

```
// CustomUserControl.swift
protocol CustomUserControlDelegate {
    func didChangeValue(value: Int)
}

class CustomUserControl: UIView {

    // Properties
    // ...
    private var value = 0 {
        didSet {
            // Possibly do something ...

            // Call delegate.
            delegate?.didChangeValue(value)
        }
    }

    var delegate: CustomUserControlDelegate?

    // ... some methods/actions associated with your user control.
}
```

Now lets assume an instance of your `CustomUserControl` is used in a a view controller, say `ViewController`. Your delegate functions for the custom control can be used in the view controller to observe key changes in the model for `CustomUserControl`, much like you'd use the inherent delegate functions of the `UITextFieldDelegate` for `UITextField` instances (e.g. `textFieldDidEndEditing(...)`).

For this simple example, use a delegate callback from the `didSet` of the class property `value` to tell a view controller that one of it's outlets have had associated model update:

```
// ViewController.swift
Import UIKit
// ...

class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomUserControlDelegate {

    // Properties
    // ...
    @IBOutlet weak var customUserControl: CustomUserControl!
        // Instance of CustomUserControl in this UIViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ...

        // Custom user control, handle through delegate callbacks.
        customUserControl.delegate = self
    }

    // ...

    // CustomUserControlDelegate
    func didChangeValue(value: Int) {
        // do some stuff with 'value' ...
    }

}
```