# How can I display value of three table at same time on one view controller in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var Table1: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var Table2: UITableView!

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should explain your question better but this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34214057/1664443

Comment: You can have multiple tableviews and use tags for each of them in order to figure out which tableview it is.

Comment: Please add a description of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In every function of the delegates, you have a `tableview` argument. You can check here which table it is like this

```
if tableview == self.Table1
{
   //Your code goes here
}
else if tableview == self.Table2
{
   //Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Since the answer has disappeared : Your function has to returns a value matching its return type in every path it can go through. So have to set a default return value if the function do not enter in any `if/else if` statement or add an `else`statement.

Answer (score 0):

Error- 
Missing return function expected in UITableView

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet var tbl1: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var tbl2: UITableView!

var tblArry1 = ["Namrata","Shweta","Shraddha"]
var tblArry2 = ["Shahade","Shirbhate","Deshmukh"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tbl1
    {
        return 1
    }
    else if tableView == self.tbl2
    {
        return 1
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tbl1
    {
        return tblArry1.count
    }
    else if tableView == self.tbl2
    {
        return tblArry2.count
    }


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView

    if tableView == self.tbl1
    {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tblArry1[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    } else if tableView == self.tbl2 {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tblArry2[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: You have an error be cause your function do. It always return something. Juste Add "else return 0" or "else return nil" at the end ans it Will be ok